# What is an idiom used for when we say something unfortunate and it comes true?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request, idiom-request, proverbs

There is a Chinese idiom 乌鸦嘴 or Crow's Mouth which means saying something unfortunate, and then it comes true. For example:

> Anthony: I think there will be a thunderstorm later
>   [Some time passes and there is a thunderstorm]
>   Brandon: You and your crow's mouth, now there is really a thunderstorm!

Otherwise it is just a response to a negative remark.

> Cody: We don't have many customers these days. I hope our boss will not cancel the year end bonus.
>   Donovan: Watch it, you and your crow's mouth!

Are there similar idioms or proverbs in English?

Comment: To croak (but it's archaic).

Answer (score 5):

One idea that comes to my mind is the verb ***jinx***.

We often say that someone *jinxes* something when something bad happens after that person has made a related comment. For example, in [this blog](http://freethinkersanonymous.com/2017/03/twistered/), a blogger writes about tornadoes. On the same day the post was published, one commenter said:

> *I think you jinxed us. Currently have several tornadoes moving through our area*.

Sometimes, though, this phrase is used when a comment is made about how things are going **well**, and then the situation changes after the comment is made. For example, in a newspaper [article](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/108148800/) about a baseball game:

> *Manager Kirk Gibson, meanwhile, thought perhaps a reporter was to blame. “I think you jinxed us,” Gibson said. “You were the one talking about how good the defense was playing, right? You should keep your mouth shut.”*

The phrase was also explained on an English [message board](https://www.italki.com/question/145355?hl=en-us):

> When someone says, "You jinxed me," it means you said something, and made it so it might happen. For example:
>
> **You**: I can't believe we got locked out of the house.
>   **Friend**: At least it's not raining!
>   [*it begins to rain*]
>   **You**: Ugh, you jinxed it!

So, your example about the upcoming raises might happen like this:

> **Cody**: We don't have many customers these days. I hope our boss will not cancel the year-end bonus.
>   **Donovan**: Shhh! Don't jinx us!

---

Note: This is fairly common parlance in the US; I'm not sure about other parts of the world.